# VBA Nullable type in function declaration

Tags: vba, ms-access

I made a function with an optional Boolean parameter.

I would like to test if the parameter was set or left blank in the function call, but apparently, when a boolean is not set, its value is still false.

I thought I could use the Nullable modifier in the function declaration but I tried all different forms of declaration:

```
Function myFunction (foo As Integer, Optional bar As Nullable(Of Boolean))
Function myFunction (foo As Integer, Optional bar As Boolean?)
Function myFunction (foo As Integer, Optional bar? As Boolean)
```

In all three cases I get a compile error saying that a list separator or ) is missing.

What would be the right syntax (or is it possible at all to do what I'm trying to do?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use Variant type for that parameter and may be IsMissing Function will be useful in that case.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. Makes so much sense that I don't understand why I didn't think of this in the first place.

Guess I am too used to strongly typed languages.